# Elegant high precision `log1p`?

Tags: evaluation, numerics, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

Sometimes it is hard to understand how numerical expressions are evaluated. I remember reading claims by Wolfram on how smart the Kernel is to evaluate expressions trees numerically by recognizing patterns, yet I don't see how it applies in very simple examples.

This question is about numerics, but to see if symbolics can help in an elegant way.

It is known that when working with finite precision, the function $\log(1+x)$ should have a special implementation for small $x$. That is why functions like `log1p` exists in many libraries (on top of `log`). [For example](http://gnu.ist.utl.pt/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Elementary-Functions.html#Elementary-Functions):

`/*C code*/ log(1. + 1.e-15) == 1.11022e-15`

`/*C code*/ log1p(1.e-15) == 1.e-15`

(The second version is more exact, the first is "wrong")

In *Mathematica*:

`Log[1. + 1.*^-15] == 1.11022*10^-15`

(wrong answer)

*Mathematica* doesn't have such `Log1P` function. One can say, well, that is because it doesn't need to, because of the symbolic power. In fact one can know the answer.

`N[Log[1 + 1/10^15], 100] = 9.999999999999995000000000000003333333333333330833333333333335333333333333331666666666666668095238095*10^-16`

But this is not general, if I want to evaluate `Log[1 + x]` and `x` has machine precision then I can't force to use something like `log1p`. Because `1+x` will evaluate to a machine precision number.

These are my attempts:

```
x = 1.*^-15;
Log[1 + x]
Log[1. + x]
N[Log[1. + N[x, 20]], 20]
N[Log[1 + N[x, 20]], 20]
```

All evaluate to the wrong answer (`1.11022*10^-15`)

Finally I find this expression,

```
N[Log[1 + Rationalize[x, 0]], 20]
9.999999999999995000*10^-16
```

But really? Is it that hard to get $\log(1+x)$ for small $x$ numerically?
Do I have to roll my own `Log1p`?

Comment: _"I remember reading claims by Wolfram on how smart the Kernel is"_ reminded me of http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2012/12/what-are-you-going-to-do-next-introducing-the-predictive-interface/

Comment: We also need the inverse of `log1p`, `expm1`, for `E^x - 1` when `x` is small.

Comment: @Ray, I suppose the trick [here](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=FJyBjjtHREQC&pg=PA22) can be used if need be.

Comment: @alfC See updated answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Update:*

yode points out in a comment below that there *are* log1p() and expm1() functions in Mathematica! However they are hidden. They are simply:

```
Internal`Log1p
Internal`Expm1
```

They operate only on numeric inputs.

(I don't know at what version these showed up.)

Compare this plot to the one further below using the `Log` function. The errors really are all zero!

```
Plot[Internal`Log1p[x]/x - 
  N[N[Log[1 + SetPrecision[x, Infinity]], 34]]/x, {x, 0.01, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: errors all zero!]

---

I don't think Mathematica has that function.  Seems like it should.  (Same for `expm1()`.)  You should not need to resort to non-machine arithmetic to get the right answer.

Here is something that will do the trick using only machine arithmetic, if the input is a machine number:

```
log1p[x_] :=
 If[MachineNumberQ[x],
  If[x < 0.5,
   If[# - 1 == 0, x,
      x Divide[Log[#], # - 1]] &[1 + x],
   Log[1 + x]],
  Log[1 + x]]
```

If it's not a machine number, then it just gives you `Log[1+x]`.

You can compile the machine number portion for much faster execution (by two orders of magnitude!):

```
log1px = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
  If[x < 0.5,
   If[# - 1 == 0, x,
      x Divide[Log[#], # - 1]] &[1 + x],
   Log[1 + x]], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

The cutoff for `x >= 0.5` is where `Log[1+x]` works just fine, with only the least significant bit varying:

```
Plot[Log[1 + x]/x - 
  N[N[Log[1 + SetPrecision[x, Infinity]], 34]]/x, {x, 0.01, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: things go south below 0.5]

Comment: "You should not need to resort to non-machine arithmetic to get the right answer.", that is my point, any solution I see is an overkill in my opinion. Does it help to `Compile` the function?

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot.  Without compiling, running it on a million random numbers in 0..0.1, I got about six seconds with no compilation, 0.4 seconds compiled to the MVM, and 0.07 seconds compiled to C.

Comment: Oh, and using arbitrary-precision numbers takes 87 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the tests! Ray's answer (and maybe Rojo's) seems to be elegant how does it compare?

Comment: Rojo's is nice if you don't mind slow (the 87 seconds example).  Ray's uses the exact same formula as mine, but does needless operations when there is no precision loss when adding 1 and _x_.  Also the use of `With` might result in calculating `1+x` more than once.  My use of a pure function assures that it is calculated once.

Comment: Returning Log[1+x] seems a nice output to have in other cases. Why would `With` evaluate `1+x` more than once? Also why did you choose `0.5` in the conditional?

Comment: I thought `With` would do that since it has the `HoldAll` attribute, and `w` appears three times in the expression.  However I put in a counter and it does in fact compute `1+x` just once.  In any case, the use of the function removes all doubt.

Comment: I use `0.5` since below that you start losing bits off the bottom when you add `1`.  Also empirically, there is no significant precision loss in `Log[1+x]` for `0.5` and above.

Comment: @MarkAdler Why did you change `/` to `Divide` (I see in your edits history)?  Are they not the same?

Comment: They are not the same. See this [question and answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39200/94).

Comment: See ``Internal`Log1p`` and ``Internal`Expm1``. :)

Comment: I tend to use `SetPrecision[x, Infinity]` instead of `Rationalize[x, 0]` for examining machine precision. The former gives the rational number (over `2^n`) corresponding to the binary representation of the machine real.  The latter gives the rational number with the least denominator that is within the error interval represented by the precision of the number.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! That works much better.

Comment: @yode How did you find those?

Comment: Sorry,no any method find these undocumental function I think.Just by a chance,I'm walking around in documentation. Such as ``Internal`AllSymbols``.You deserve it,too.

Comment: @yode When there's a standard name, I try ``?*`Log1p`` or rather ``?*`*og1*`` taking most of the standard name and wildcarding things that might or might not be capitalized and so forth.  Sometimes, though, you get hundreds of hits and it's not so helpful.  Some people do a similar thing with `Names[]`.

Comment: Just a side note: ``Internal`Log1p`` and ``Internal`Expm1`` are not in _v9.0.1_.

Answer (score 20):

David Goldberg (["What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic"](https://doi.org/10.1145/103162.103163), *ACM Computing Surveys*, Vol **23**, No 1, March 1991, p 12, Th 4) gives pseudocode that is equivalent to

```
log1p[x_Real] := With[{w = 1 + x}, If[w - 1 == 0, x, x * Log @ w/(w - 1)]]
```

EDIT - Following Mark Adler's comments, I checked the binary representation of the results (using `RealDigits[#,2,53]`) for `x` in `Range[1.,5.,.25]*2^-52` against the value returned by setting the precision to 35, and he is right on both counts: the comparison should be `w-1 == 0`, not `w === 1.`, and the division should use the `a/b` form, not the `Divide[a,b]` form. I have changed the code accordingly.

---

```
LogLogPlot[{log1p[x], Log[1 + x]}, {x, 1*^-17, 1*^-14}]
```

[image: log1p]

Comment: Very elegant solution. I hope you don't mind that I added a plot to illustrate the result. (Probably the same as most of other answers).

Comment: Same answer as mine, except it does needless operations for large _x_.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I omitted a check for large `x`. I also used `1.` instead of the `1` that would handle cases in which `x` has more than machine precision. As for being the same, note that `w === 1.` is not the same as `w - 1 == 0`, and `Divide[a,b]` is not the same as `a/b` for machine precision numbers.

Comment: You are correct, and in fact in this case `w - 1 == 0` is preferred.  `w === 1.` will return true for a number that is not exactly `1.` !  However `w - 1 == 0` will not.  Try it for `w = 1. + 2*10^-16`.  You will find that `w - 1 == 0` is false, `w === 1` is true, and `w - 1.` is not zero.

Comment: How is `Divide[a,b]` and `a/b` different?  That's a new one on me.  The documentation indicates that they mean the same thing, and when I use `InputForm` on them, I get the same result.  Can you give an example where they are different?

Comment: @MarkAdler according to Daniel Lichtblau recently in comments on another answer, `a/b` converts into `a*1/b` before evaluation, whereas `Divide` does the division directly. This could be important when we work with machine-precision numbers, but is not documented anywhere AFAIK.

Comment: Interesting.  Did Daniel give an example where the result is different?

Comment: FYI, I get very slightly better results with mine using `Divide` instead of `/`.  The root-mean-square error goes down from `1.19*(10^-16)` to `1.13*(10^-16)`.  I have updated mine to use `Divide`.

Answer (score 9):

I think that is because `1.` and `1.*^-15` are *machine-precision* numbers, and Mathematica does NOT do [precision-tracking](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html) on machine-precision calculations. I suggust using the *arbitrary-precision* numbers instead.

```
Through[{Precision, Accuracy}@#] & /@ {1., 1.*^-15}
```

> {{MachinePrecision, 15.9546}, {MachinePrecision, 30.9546}}

Now we specify a precision to the numbers to make them arbitrary-precision numbers:

```
res = Log[1.`20 + 1.`20*^-15]
```

> 1.000*10^-15

```
Through[{Precision, Accuracy}[res]]
```

> {5., 20.}

And it won't be wrong even for low precision cases:

```
res2 = Log[1.`5 + 1.`5*^-15]
```

> 0.*10^-5

```
Through[{Precision, Accuracy}[res2]]
```

> {0., 5.}

Answer (score 8):

### Problem

The problem with `Log[1. + 1.*^-15]` not yielding `1.*^-15` is not due to `Log`, but to `MachinePrecision` inputs, which I think the OP implied in the question statement:

```
1 + 1.*^-15
% - 1
(*
  1.
  1.11022*10^-15
*)
```

So `Log[1 + 1.*^-15]` does return the right answer, `1.11022*10^-15`, for the actual input.

#### Solution

Here is a simple way to get `log1p`-type evaluation:

```
log1p[x_] := x Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 2, -x];

log1p[1.*^-15]
(*  1.*10^-15  *)
```

One needs to be careful, because `log1p[x]` evaluates to `Log[1+x]` when `x` is symbolic and you lose the precision:

```
log1p[x] /. x -> 1.*^-15
(*  1.11022*10^-15  *)
```

To prevent this, one can use the `Precision` tricks in the other answers, or use `?NumericQ` and clear the previous definition.  For instance

```
log1p[x] /. x -> SetPrecision[1.*^-15, $MachinePrecision] // N
(*  1.*10^-15  *)
```

or

```
ClearAll[log1p];
log1p[x_?NumericQ] := x Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 2, -x];

log1p[x] /. x -> 1.*^-15
(*  1.*10^-15  *)
```

Of course, in this second method, you lose the symbolic equivalence to `Log[1+x]`.  But all the other current solutions suffer the same drawbacks of one or the other definitions of `log1p` that are given here.

#### Addendum: expm1

The function

```
expm1[x_] := x Hypergeometric1F1[1, 2, x];
```

can be used like `log1p` above.

Comment: This is pretty clever! I know for a fact that the hypergeometric functions in *Mathematica* were carefully written to be able to deal with arguments at or near $1$, and this carefulness is exploited here to compute $\log(1+x)$. For `expm1`, `x MittagLefflerE[1, 2, x]` works as well.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I wasn't familiar with `MittagLefflerE`.  [It seems slower](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SpJlK.png), though.

Answer (score 8):

```
LogLogPlot[{Internal`Log1p[x], Log[1 + x]}, {x, 1*^-17, 1*^-14}]
```

[image]

ps：Of course,maybe you need `` Internal`Expm1 ``,too.

Comment: Well-found! +1 :-)

Comment: Note ``Internal`Log1p`` and ``Internal`Expm1`` are new in V11.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't know it is added in V11.  :)

Comment: I just checked V10.4.1. (Indeed, I'm pretty sure I checked last year, when I wrote my answer.)  Perhaps this Q&A made WRI think about adding them.  (But IMO, they are the wrong functions to add. What one really needs is `Log1p[x]/x` etc., like `Sinc[x]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't think WRI will response SE so positive.I posted so many bug post but those problem still.  :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 It don't make sense they ignore those post taged with **bugs**.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps

```
SetAttributes[log1p, NumericFunction];

N[log1p[x_?MachineNumberQ], _] := N@log1p[SetPrecision[x, $MachinePrecision]];

N[log1p[x_?NumericQ], {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}] := 
  N@N[log1p[x], $MachinePrecision];

N[log1p[x_?NumericQ], a_] := N[Log[1 + x], a]
```

**EDIT**
This probably makes more sense

```
ClearAll[log1p]

log1p[x_?MachineNumberQ] := N@log1p[SetPrecision[x, $MachinePrecision]];
log1p[x_?InexactNumberQ] := Log[1 + x];
```

Comment: Nice defination. But the underlying `Precision` and `Accuracy` can go wrong for some cases?

Comment: How is this function used? I get back the unevaluated `log1p[1.*^-15`.

Comment: @alfC, only through `N`, but you are right, I should have made it evaluate automatically. I am not sure why I went this road. Probably sleep depravation

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[log1p]

log1p[x_, 
  n : _Integer?Positive : 
   2] := (Series[Log[1 + y], {y, 0, n}] // Normal) /. y -> x

log1p[1.0*^-15]
```

> 9.999999999999995*^-16

Comment: One might consider using `PadeApproximant[]` instead…

Comment: @J.M. - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
z = 10.^-15;
N[z/(z/2 + 1), 100]

log1pcontracted[z_,n:_Integer?Positive:2]:=(2z)/(2+z+((-10-5 z) z^2)/(60+z (60+11 z)+Fold[#2[[1]]/(#2[[2]]+#1)&,0,Transpose[{Table[-(324+m (1224+m (1812+m (1312+m (464+64 m)))))z^4/(5+4m),{m,n,0,-1}],Table[(1260+z (1260+154 z)+m (2288+z (2288+284 z)+m (1344+z (1344+168 z)+m (256+z (256+32 z)))))/(5+4m),{m,n,0,-1}]}]]));
log1p[z_,n:_Integer?Positive:2]:=2z/(2+z+Fold[#2[[1]]/(#2[[2]]+#1)&,0,Transpose[{Table[-(m-1)^2z^2,{m,n,2,-1}],Table[(2m-1)(2+z),{m,n,2,-1}]}]]);
log1pcontractedcompiled=Compile[{n,z},(2z)/(2+z+((-10-5 z) z^2)/(60+z (60+11 z)+Fold[#2[[1]]/(#2[[2]]+#1)&,0,Transpose[{Table[-(324+m (1224+m (1812+m (1312+m (464+64 m)))))z^4/(5+4m),{m,n,0,-1}],Table[(1260+z (1260+154 z)+m (2288+z (2288+284 z)+m (1344+z (1344+168 z)+m (256+z (256+32 z)))))/(5+4m),{m,n,0,-1}]}]]))];
log1pcompiled=Compile[{n,z},2z/(2+z+Fold[#2[[1]]/(#2[[2]]+#1)&,0,Transpose[{Table[-(m-1)^2z^2,{m,n,2,-1}],Table[(2m-1)(2+z),{m,n,2,-1}]}]])];

N[log1p[z], 100]

N[log1pcontracted[z], 100]

N[log1pcompiled[2, z], 100]

N[log1pcontractedcompiled[2, z], 100]
```

Comment: Is this the continued fraction? If so, consider using a forward evaluation method so as not to waste effort nor need to have to specify a truncation.

Comment: yes, continued fraction