# Is there a difference between Divide[a,b] and a/b?

Tags: numerics, machine-precision, arithmetic

In [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39126/elegant-high-precision-log1p#comment-117171) it was asserted that `Divide[a,b]` and `a/b` are different, though the documentation [indicates that they are the same](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Divide.html).  In particular, it was asserted that `a/b` is evaluated as `a * 1/b`, whereas `Divide[a,b]` performs the division directly.  It was further asserted that this could result in an observable difference in behavior for machine-precision numbers.

The question is: is there a difference?  If so, what is it exactly?  How does it manifest itself?  Is there an example where `Divide` gives a different result than `/`?

I tried a few edge cases with `$MaxMachineNumber` and `$MinMachineNumber`, but didn't find any differences in behavior between the two.

Comment: The answer is still the same as it was [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2013/Nov/msg00012.html). The prior post in that thread has examples that show different behavior.

Comment: Ah, someone's here from Wolfram.  That's good.  I would assert that this behavior of `/` in a numerical expression is a _bug_.  `/` should always give the most accurate result on machine numbers, but it currently does not.  As it stands, I now have to use `Divide` wherever `/` used to be in order to get the correct result.  That is a giant pain, since I suddenly lose 800 years of development of a convenient mathematical notation.

Comment: And yes, I will also submit a bug report in the official manner.

Comment: I made inquiries about the feasibility of changing the evaluation parsing/semantics of '/' to be like Divide. I was informed that this was considered some time ago, and rejected, because it would be backwardly incompatible for situations where HoldXXX are in play. I guess more generally it would create trouble if '/' was not an infix surrogate for '*' (with inversion of the right hand argument). Reason being, a chain like `a*b/c*d*e/f*g` would no longer parse to something with head of `Times` and seven arguments.

Comment: The classic "too hard to fix" response to a bug.  C'mon, you guys are smart.  Suppose you retained information about the split of the original divide operation so that the multiplication and reciprocal could be recombined into a division when the time came to actually do the operation?

Comment: Or, you could defer the split of `Divide[]` until a symbolic operation comes into play.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Oleksandr is correct about the way evaluation works.  `a/b` seems to be interpreted (parsed) directly as `Times[a, Power[b,-1]]`, or more readably: $a\times b^{-1}$.  `Divide[a,b]` is interpreted as is.  Evaluation then proceeds from these forms, and the arithmetic is carried out differently for the two cases: either $a\times (1/b)$ or $a/b$.

Here are some examples that illustrate the evaluation sequence:

```
In[95]:= 
On[]
Divide[4,8]
Off[]

During evaluation of In[95]:= On::trace: On[] --> Null. >>
During evaluation of In[95]:= Divide::trace: 4/8 --> 1/2. >>

Out[96]= 1/2

In[98]:= 
On[]
4/8
Off[]

During evaluation of In[98]:= On::trace: On[] --> Null. >>
During evaluation of In[98]:= Power::trace: 1/8 --> 1/8. >>
During evaluation of In[98]:= Times::trace: 4/8 --> 4/8. >>
During evaluation of In[98]:= Times::trace: 4/8 --> 1/2. >>

Out[99]= 1/2
```

This can indeed theoretically lead to different machine precision results.  Let's find out if it really does!  We are going to compare the complete binary representation of the results, and we won't use `==` or `===` (which *both* have some tolerance).

```
Table[{k, RealDigits[k/137., 2] === RealDigits[Divide[k, 137.], 2]}, {k, 1, 20}]

(* ==> {{1, True}, {2, True}, {3, True}, {4, True}, {5, True}, {6, True}, {7, True}, 
        {8, True}, {9, True}, {10, True}, {11, True}, {12, True}, {13, True}, 
        {14, True}, {15, False}, {16, True}, {17, True}, {18, True}, {19, True}, {20, True}} 
 *)
```

So `Divide[15, 137.]` and `15/137.` really do lead to different results.  **Conclusion: yes, there is an observable difference.**

Again, keep in mind that even `===` has some tolerance (`` Internal`$SameQTolerance ``) when comparing machine precision numbers (though less than `==`, `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``) and `15/137. === Divide[15, 137.]` returns `True`.  The difference is there though as evidenced by the full 53-bit binary representation.

So will you ever see the effects of this in practice?  Theoretically the error may accumulate, and there are some functions which do not honour these tolerances and perform strict comparisons (try e.g. `Union[{15/137., Divide[15, 137.]}]`, which returns a list of length 2).

Comment: Sure enough.  `Divide[15, 137.] - 15/137.` gives `1.38778*10^-17`.  Fascinating.

Comment: By camparing with `N[15/137, 100]`, `15/137.` looks preciser. Does `a/b` always preciser than `Divide[a, b]` for machine-precision `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Silvia If you compare the binary digits directly, using `RealDigits[..., 2]`, you'll see that all binary digits of `Divide[15,137.]` are correct, but the last two binary digits of `15/137.` are wrong.  Generally the `Divide` form is more likely to be correct because it is a result of a single division.  The `/` form is the result of two operations: a division and a multiplication, so roundoff errors may accumulate.

Comment: The documentation (which we have already established as incorrect) indicates that $a\div b$ (`a[esc]div[esc]b`) is another way to write `Divide[a,b]`.  However it is actually interpreted as `a/b`.  I think that documentation needs some work.

Comment: @MarkAdler Some more observations:  `HoldComplete[Divide[a,b]]` prints as HoldComplete[$\frac{a}{b}$], but it does actually keep the internal representation as `Divide` (as shown by `FullForm`). However, typing `HoldComplete[Divide[a,b]]` and then pressing Command-Shift-N to convert to StandardForm destroys `Divide`, and replaces it with `/`.  Evaluating it and using `FullForm` gives `Times[a,Power[b,-1]]`.

Comment: Hmm.. That is different from my observation.. I [compared all `Divide[k, n]` vs `k/n` for `k` and `n` both from `1` to `200`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/93V1w.png). Looks like the chance is 50-50.

Comment: FWIW, here is my code: `res=Table[MapThread[#1@#2&,{{(len=Length[#];#)&[RealDigits[#,2][[1]]]&,RealDigits[#,2][[1]]&,RealDigits[#,2][[1,1;;len]]&},{Divide[k,SetPrecision[n,MachinePrecision]],k/SetPrecision[n,MachinePrecision],N[k/n,100]}}]//Length/@{LongestCommonSubsequence[#[[1]],#[[3]]],LongestCommonSubsequence[#[[2]],#[[3]]]}&//#1-#2&@@#&,{n,1,200},{k,1,200}]`

Comment: Any theories about why Mathematica automatically goes the weird way?

Answer (score 6):

I have just a little to add to @Szabolcs' answer, and this seemed an appropriate place rather than a separate Q&A. Since there is a theorem involved (see below), it should be pointed out that this theorem tends to fail to hold in *Mathematica*.  Well, wait, it's a theorem: it must true!  Then let us say that it tends to be difficult to apply this theorem to *Mathematica* code.

As pointed out already, `a / b` is short for `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]`, which involves two roundings.  It also happens that sometimes `Divide[a, b]` evaluates to `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]`, for example, symbolically and in some cases presented below.  In fact, I sometimes find it difficult to get `Divide` to `Divide[]` and not to multiply by the reciprocal.

There's a remarkable theorem for base-10 addicts due to W. Kahan (see [David Goldberg, "What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic", ACM Computing Surveys, Vol 23, No 1, March 1991, 5–48, Theorem 7](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/103162.103163)):

> *Suppose $x$ is an integer with $|x|<2^{p-1}$ in a binary floating-point format with precision $p$ bits and floating-point operations that are exactly rounded. Then if $n$ is an integer of the form $n = 2^i + 2^j$ (such as $n=10$), then $(x \,/\, n) \times n = x$ (exactly).*

Unsurprisingly, this theorem does not apply if $x \,/\, n$ is computed as `Times[x, Power[n, -1]]`.

According to the theorem, all the totals below should be zero.

```
(*** N.B.: Vectorized FAILS ***)
(Divide[#, 10.]*10. - #) &[
   N@Range@32] // Unitize // Total
(*** WORKS on short packed arrays?  ***)
(Divide[#, 10.]*10. - #) &[
   N@Range@31] // Unitize // Total
(*** No, wait! Vectorized sometimes WORKS!!  ***)
(Divide[#, ConstantArray[10., Length@#]]*10. - #) &[
   N@Range@32] // Unitize // Total
(*** WORKS on unpacked arrays? ***)
(Divide[#, 10.]*10. - #) &[
   N@Range@32 // Developer`FromPackedArray] // Unitize // Total
(*** Nope, FAILS on large arrays! Maybe gets repacked/compiled? ***)
(Divide[#, 10.]*10. - #) &[
   N@Range@251 // Developer`FromPackedArray] // Unitize // Total
(*
  9   -- 32 numbers:    FAILURE
  0   -- 31 numbers:    SUCCESS
  0   -- Double array:  SUCCESS
  0   -- Unpacked 32:   SUCCESS
  65  -- Unpacked >250: FAILURE
*)
```

Perhaps we're seeing some patterns, but the `Trace` the command changes the computational environment and results:

```
ReleaseHold@Last@Trace[Divide[#, 10.]] - Divide[#, 10.] &[
   N@Range@32] // Unitize // Total
(*  11  *)

ReleaseHold@Last@Trace[Divide[#, 10.]*10. - #] &@[
   N@Range@32] // Unitize // Total
(*  0 *)
```

These are not consistent with the first result, although both are computed from the same input `N@Range@32`. Apparently `Trace` prevents `Divide` from converting to multiplying by the reciprocal.

On my system (Intel i7/Macbook Pro), we can address the two failures with system options:

```
SetSystemOptions[
 "ParallelOptions" -> (* originally {128, 32, 32} *)
  "VectorVendorLengthThresholds" -> {128, 32, Infinity}]

SetSystemOptions[
 "PackedArrayOptions" -> (* originally 250 *)
  "ListableAutoPackLength" -> Infinity]
```

It's been noted elsewhere that `Divide[a, b]` is faster than `a/b`:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[Divide[##]] & @@ RandomReal[1, {2, 10^7}]
(*  0.026914  *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[#1/#2] & @@ RandomReal[1, {2, 10^7}]
(*  0.05279  *)
```

It seems completely consistent with `Divide[a, b]` having half as many FLOPS as `a/b`.  It's too bad there isn't a reliable way to implement it.

---

Addendum: A criticism of `x * (1/y)`.

> The recently well-publicized flaw in floating-point division on the Pentium chip has prompted the question whether $\tt x/y$ may simply be replaced by $\tt x*(1/y)$. This note focuses on the example $y=x$ illustrating that this proposed fix would no longer conform to the IEEE standard. --- [Edelman, "When is $x*(1/x)\ne1$" (1994)](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Eedelman/homepage/papers/ieee.pdf)