# About auto-compiling and performance between Do and Fold

Tags: performance-tuning, functional-style

I was investigating how `Fold` could improve performance vs `Do`. I tested the code

```
AbsoluteTiming[
   sum = 1.0;
   inc = 1.0;
   Do[inc = inc*Sin[10.5]/i; sum = sum + Tan[inc], {i, 10^5}];
   sum]
```

The output is

```
Out[] = {2.303896, 0.105747}
```

I have hoped that using `Fold` could improve the performance:

```
AbsoluteTiming@ 
    Fold[{#[[1]]*Sin[10.5]/(#2 + 1), #[[2]] + Tan@#[[1]]} &,
        {Sin[10.5], 1.0}, N@Range[10^5]]
```

However, this code is not faster:

```
Out[] = {2.471189, {-5.537337857006675*10^-462146, 0.105747}}
```

I have some questions concerning the above example:

(1) [Partially solved. See EDIT] Why the `Fold` here is not faster? I thought it should have been auto-compiled and thus faster. But it didn't.

(2) [Solved. See EDIT] Here Mathematica is using precision much higher than double precision (by having number as small as 10^{-462146}). Would it be possible to set precision to boost performance? I tried `SetPricision` and `SetAccuracy`. The precision changes but it doesn't improve performance.

(3) [Solved. See Mr. Wizard's example in his answer] Another problem of `Fold` is that one has first to generate a long list (length 10^5 in this example). For much larger list, the `Fold` method may use too much memory. Is it possible to use functional way (not necessarily `Fold`) in a more memory-efficient way?

Thank you very much!

PS: I met this question when trying to reproduce Mr.Wizard's answer of the below thread, with some modifications. I can reproduce Wizard's result, where `Fold` boots the performance greatly compared with `Do`. But I don't understand why my above example is not as good.

[Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)

**EDIT:**

(a) Rojo's comment is the answer of (2):  `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]`

(b) About the performance of Fold: on Mathematica v7 after disabling `CatchMachineUnderflow`, the Fold code is 10x faster then Do code. However, on Mathematica v9 the Fold code is a bit slower than Do. This seems like a regression in Mathematica. For comparison, this code has 10x improvement than the Do version: `Fold[# + Sin[#2] &, 1.0, Range[10^6]]` both on v7 and v9.

Comment: Perhaps you have to decrease `"FoldCompileLength" -> 100`? As detalied here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1816/745. Also your function can easily be compiled manually, giving you more control (for example you can compile to C etc...)

Comment: @Ajasja : Thanks for the comment! I think 10^5 is greater than 100 and thus Fold should have compiled (but it didn't). I have just tried "FoldCompileLength" 1, 50, Infinity. All have the same performance. Indeed, this code can be compiled to C. I actually tried that and did some benchmarks at [here](http://cosmosimple.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/some-benchmarks-of-mathematica-vs.html). Nevertheless I'd like to learn if functional programming could do better than Do-loop.

Comment: You can try with `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]` to avoid the low numbers

Comment: @Rojo : Thanks! This answers one of my questions! The performance is improved by 10x. Fold is still no faster than Do though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In version 7, after setting the option that Rojo described, your `Fold` code is nearly an order of magnitude faster than `Do`:

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False];

AbsoluteTiming[
 sum = 1.0;
 inc = 1.0;
 Do[inc = inc*Sin[10.5]/i; sum = sum + Tan[inc], {i, 10^6}];
 sum
]
```

> ```
> {2.0100028, 0.105747}
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming@
 Fold[{(#[[1]] Sin[10.5])/(#2 + 1), #[[2]] + Tan[#[[1]]]} &, {Sin[10.5], 1.0}, 
  N@Range[10^6]]
```

> ```
> {0.2500003, {0., 0.105747}}
> ```

The `Fold` code can be made faster still with a few optimizations:

```
sin = Sin[10.5];

AbsoluteTiming[
 Fold[
   {Divide[#[[1]] sin, #2], #[[2]] + Tan[#[[1]]]} &,
   {sin, 1.0}, 
   Range[2, 10^6 + 1]
 ]
]
```

> ```
> {0.1600025, {0., 0.105747}}
> ```

In this case splitting the operations and vectorizing `Tan` yields a greater improvement:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 1 + Tr @ Tan @ FoldList[Divide[# sin, #2] &, sin, Range[2, 10^6 + 1]]
]
```

> ```
> {0.0600001, 0.105747}
> ```

This may use additional memory, but trading memory consumption for greater speed is a common programming compromise.  If you need to work with longer lists you can split the list into sections and use the output of one `Fold` as the input for the next:

```
Fold[
  Fold[{Divide[#[[1]] sin, #2], #[[2]] + Tan[#[[1]]]} &, #, Range[#2, #2 + 10000]] &,
  {sin, 1.0},
  Range[2, 10^7, 10000]
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.8000025, {0., 0.105747}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very interesting. However, I still cannot reproduce your achievements on Mathematica 9 (and don't have M7 to test). On my machine with M9, your Fold code uses a little longer time then Do. I noticed on my machine CompileOptions->AutomaticCompile is by default False. I set it to True but it doesn't help. Is there a way to debug why Mathematica doesn't compile the code, or any other suggestions? (Explicit Compile command works on my machine)

Comment: And it is very strange that for your previous example on Fold [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) I can reproduce that Fold is about 20x faster than Do. But on your current answer every Fold example takes about 10x longer on my machine (while Do example takes about the same time).

Comment: I have also tested that if I consider a similar (but different) problem: Fold[# + Sin[#2] &, 1.0, Range[10^6]]. This is 10x faster than Do on my machine. But somehow if # is a list as in the example on my question, the performance breaks down.

Comment: @YiWang I'm afraid I can't be of help because I don't have v9, but I hope that someone else can and will answer your questions.

Comment: I found that I have access to v7. I tested your examples on v7 and the performance is similar to those you gave. Thus my problem may be a regression on v9? I think I had better accept your answer, and discuss this regression elsewhere. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Simple and fast method:

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False];
inc = 1.0;
a = Sin[10.5];
1 + Sum[Tan[inc *= Divide[a, n]], {n, 10^5}]
```

It is about 70% faster than your example with `Do`.

See also: [Is there a difference between Divide[a,b] and a/b?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39200)

Comment: Thanks! It is interesting to see Divide is different from /. Also it's clever to use Sum here!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand why you using `Fold` here. Using `FoldList` instead would give you much simple and faster code:

```
Total@Tan@FoldList[Times, Table[Sin[10.5]/i, {i, 10^5}]] + 1 // AbsoluteTiming
```