# Performance regression for Fold?

Tags: compile, core-language, system-performance, backslide

I noticed an over 10x performance drop on Mathematica v9.0.1 (as Oleksandr R. commented, also v8) compared with v7.01 for this code:

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False];
AbsoluteTiming@ 
 Fold[{(#[[1]] Sin[10.5])/(#2 + 1), #[[2]] + Tan[#[[1]]]} &,
   {Sin[10.5], 1.0}, N@Range[10^6]]
```

I got `{0.184287, {0., 0.105747}}` on v7, but got `{2.311755, {0., 0.105747}}` on v9. Note that the Do[...] version of above code needs about 2 seconds. Thus I suspect that on v9 the Fold code is not properly auto-compiled.

Is this a regression? (Also is there a way to see if auto-compile worked or not?)

**Additional information**

I compared that in v7 and v9 the CompileOptions are the same (except that v9 has some options that are not present in v7):

```
SystemOptions[CompileOptions]
```

> {"CompileOptions" -> {"ApplyCompileLength" -> [Infinity], 
>          "ArrayCompileLength" -> 250, "AutoCompileAllowCoercion" -> False, 
>          "AutoCompileProtectValues" -> False, "AutomaticCompile" -> False, 
>          "BinaryTensorArithmetic" -> False, "CompileAllowCoercion" -> True, 
>          "CompileConfirmInitializedVariables" -> True, 
>          "CompiledFunctionArgumentCoercionTolerance" -> 2.10721, 
>          "CompiledFunctionMaxFailures" -> 3, 
>          "CompileDynamicScoping" -> False, 
>          "CompileEvaluateConstants" -> True, 
>          "CompileOptimizeRegisters" -> False, 
>          "CompileParallelizationThreshold" -> 10, 
>          "CompileReportCoercion" -> False, "CompileReportExternal" -> False,
>           "CompileReportFailure" -> False, "CompileValuesLast" -> True, 
>          "FoldCompileLength" -> 100, "InternalCompileMessages" -> False, 
>          "ListableFunctionCompileLength" -> 250, "MapCompileLength" -> 100, 
>          "NestCompileLength" -> 100, "NumericalAllowExternal" -> False, 
>          "ProductCompileLength" -> 250, "ReuseTensorRegisters" -> True, 
>          "SumCompileLength" -> 250, "SystemCompileOptimizations" -> All, 
>          "TableCompileLength" -> 250}}

To compare, I also tried the following code, where the performance on v7 and v9 are roughly the same (v9 is on average 5% more slowly though).

```
AbsoluteTiming@Fold[# + Sin[#2] &, 1.0, Range[10^6]]
```

A difference is that here the first argument of function in Fold is a number, and in the problematic example, the first argument is a list.

PS: I noticed this issuee during a discussion at [About auto-compiling and performance between Do and Fold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41103/about-auto-compiling-and-performance-between-do-and-fold) . But considering this regression issue is a different question, I ask here separately.

Comment: Note that it is not customary to use the "bugs" tag until we have confirmation from WRI or consensus in the community that it is really a bug. However, in this particular case, the regression is so obvious that tagging it as a bug right away seems justified.

Comment: Incidentally, version 8 is somehow intermediate between 7 and 9. Its performance is closer to that of version 9 than to 7, but about 10% faster than the former. So I think it would be fair to say that the major regression occurred in version 8, but nobody noticed until now.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks for the comment! I will be careful in using a bug tag in the future, but keep it for the time being as you advised.

Comment: I get `{5.068002, {0., 0.105747}}` on version 10. Seems like it wasn't fixed.

Comment: This bug is still present in 10.2

Comment: After seeing @[ilian](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian)'s [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94113/), I have to reconsider the status of this as a bug, because it is obviously caused by numerical overflow in user code. I am de-tagging appropriately. If anyone disagrees, please roll back and let's discuss it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that autocompilation always uses settings equivalent to `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"Quality", "WarningMessages" -> False}`.

As previously noted in [Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/17/silvia)'s answer, the automatic compilation is invoked for input exceeding

```
SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "FoldCompileLength"]

(* {"CompileOptions" -> {"FoldCompileLength" -> 100}} *)
```

however, when $n$ becomes greater than 165, the compiled function interpreter switches to uncompiled evaluation because of machine underflow. This can be seen if we compile the function ourselves,

```
cf0 = Compile[{{arg, _Real, 1}}, Fold[{(#[[1]] Sin[10.5])/(#2 + 1), 
        #[[2]] + Tan[#[[1]]]} &, {Sin[10.5], 1.0}, arg], "RuntimeOptions" -> "Quality"];

cf0[N[Range[165]]]

(* {6.37932*10^-308, 0.105747} *)

cf0[N[Range[166]]]

(* CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 12; 
proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

  {-3.360393999426673*10^-310, 0.105747} 

*)
```

where the first element in the last result is not a machine number.

The speed can be recovered by turning off underflow checking, for example

```
cf = Compile[{{arg, _Real, 1}}, Fold[{(#[[1]] Sin[10.5])/(#2 + 1), 
       #[[2]] + Tan[#[[1]]]} &, {Sin[10.5], 1.0}, arg], "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"];

AbsoluteTiming[cf[N[Range[10^6]]]]

(* {0.202218, {0., 0.105747}} *)
```

As for why version 7 is different, I am not completely sure. The more fine-grained control allowed by [`"RuntimeOptions"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html) did not exist before the compiler overhaul in version 8. Earlier than that, it is possible that all machine arithmetic exception handling was controlled by the legacy `"CatchMachineUnderflow"` system option (first implemented in 1999).

Given that automatic compilation is invisible to the user, I am inclined to believe that always using the safer `"RuntimeOptions" -> "Quality"` was a conscious design choice. Explicit compilation should be used if other exception handling scenarios are desired.

Comment: Based on your answer I'm strongly inclined to remove the "bugs" tag. Thanks for looking into this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer! I didn't realize there is an underflow.

Answer (score 16):

*(This is not an answer, but only a phenomenon I observed. And I think it might be a bug.)*

I think in version 9, Mathematica fails to compile the `Fold` for $n\geq 166$ where $n$ is the integer number in `Range`. The precise threshold may be different from OS to OS, but I suspect this phenomenon exists in all version 9.

Note the default `"FoldCompileLength"` is `100`:

```
"CompileOptions" /. SystemOptions["CompileOptions"] // "FoldCompileLength" /. # &
```

> 100

Now take a look at the steps of the whole evaluation chain for different $n$:

```
evalSteps = Map[(
                    steps = 0;
                    TraceScan[steps++ &,
                        Fold[{(#1[[1]] Sin[10.5])/(#2 + 1), #1[[2]] + 
                                        Tan[#1[[1]]]} &, {Sin[10.5], 1.0}, N[Range[#]]],
                        _,
                        TraceInternal -> True, TraceOff -> _Message];
                    {#, steps}) &,
            Range[1, 500]];

ListLinePlot[evalSteps, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: strange failure of compile?]

So it seems to suggest that auto-compilation occurs correctly at $n=100$, but strangely fails for $n\geq 166$.

However, a close checking of the evaluation chains returned from `Trace` (along with the `levelIndentFunc` I described in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26056/17)) reveals that auto-compilation might occur correctly for $n\geq 166$ too, but mma somehow falls back to uncompiled version after then. The following comparison is between $n=166$ and $n=165$:

[image: comparison between succeeded and failed cases]

Comment: I can confirm the exact same behaviour on Linux Mint Debian with both Mathematica 8 and 9.

Comment: @sebhofer Thanks for checking it!

Comment: I confirm this behavior with *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this on [wolframcloud.com](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) and got completely different results and a much slower computation time:

```
AbsoluteTiming@ 
 Fold[{(#[[1]] Sin[10.5])/(#2 + 1), #[[2]] + Tan[#[[1]]]} &,
   {Sin[10.5], 1.0}, N@Range[10^6]]
```

$\{0.41532,\{0.,0.107\}\}$

I got the opinion that v13.0 is more capable of solving this problem.

Comment: -1 By now, hardware differences between the machine on which OP reported timings 7 years ago and the machine on which Wolfram Cloud operates today will likely obfuscate any version-dependent enhancements.

Comment: There's also [the change in how underflow is handled](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#104693557) in V11.3.

Comment: I am getting 0.105747 for that last value, both on Wolfram Cloud and a desktop Mathematica. Was there a copy-paste error?