# Why IntegerPart[x/(x/2)]=1?

Tags: numerics

Consider this code

```
x = 0.109354682484;
IntegerPart[x/(x/2)]
(* 1 *)

Precision[x]
(* MachinePrecision *)
```

Why does it give 1 ?

Version number: 9.0 on Mac 10.9.2

screenshot

[image]

**Update:**

If we use an undefined variable, `IntegerPart[x0/(x0/2)]` gives 2. Since Mathematica never gives warnings about this `x0`, I'm assuming for any `x0` it is true.

If we calculate the same integer part using fortran, we get 2 instead of 1.

```
program main
implicit none

real(8):: x=0.109354682484
real(8):: y=1.4

write(*,*) int(x/(x/2))
write(*,*) nint(x/(x/2))
write(*,*) int(y)

end program main
```

compiled with ifort -O0 main.f90

output of above fortran code is

```
       2
       2
       1
```

according to [here](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap02/funct.html), int is a fortran intrinsic function that calculate the integer part.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Look at the `FullForm` of the result of `x/(x/2)`.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but why fortran gives 2, with the same precision?

Comment: Then I guess it comes down to what you want `IntegerPart[1.9999999999999998]` to return?

Comment: Does your Fortran compiler optimize the expression `x/(x/2)`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I only use -O0 option but I don't know whether there are other optimizations. Are you aware of other optimizations?

Comment: As a general rule, you should never rely on an exact comparison when doing floating point calculations; e.g. you should never expect reasonable behavior near a discontinuity of any function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explanation is interesting here.  I tried the same in C++, and worked a bit extra to make sure the compiler won't optimize away the divisions (looking at the assembly output, it may optimize it away if you're not careful).  Indeed, I get `2` with C++.

And here's why:

C++ does the equivalent of

```
IntegerPart@Divide[x, Divide[x, 2]]

(* ==> 2 *)
```

while in Mathematica you're computing the equivalent of

```
x*(1/((1/2)*x))
```

which gives a different result.

If I do the calculation as `(x* (1/ (0.5*x)))` in C++, then the result is less than 2 and the integer part is 1.

Relevant reading:

- [Is there a difference between Divide[a,b] and a/b?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39200/is-there-a-difference-between-dividea-b-and-a-b)

Comment: Thanks! I never knew that a/b is interpreted as a*(1/b). That makes me worried a little bit about all the codes I have written. Actually I caught on this because of a strange behavior of my package, and it took me a whole morning to track down to problem to `IntegerPart` I used in that package.

Comment: The observed behavior is wrong under IEEE-754 as well as generic binary floating-point implementations.  The result of `x/2` or `0.5 * 2` has the same mantissa as `x`, and the exponent is decreased by one.  Dividing two numbers having the same mantissa then results in a mantissa of 1 (stored implicitly), and the exponent is the difference in operand exponents.  The only way for a binary implementation to not get exactly `2` for the result of `x/(x/2)` or `x/(0.5*x)` is if the scaled value becomes denormal.

Comment: @BenVoigt But as I said it does not compute `x/(0.5*x)`.  It computes `x * (1/(0.5*x))`.  I don't know what's correct by the standard, but the result is precisely the same as what I get from C++, which just uses a few simple floating point instructions (based on the asm output).  Mathematica also uses hardware floating point arithmetic by default.

Comment: @BenVoigt The reason why it does the arithmetic in this order is explained in the post I linked to.

Comment: Oh right, I thought about only one reciprocal and there are two.