# IntegerPart - is this a known bug?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, number-representation

I'm working in Mathematica 13.0 and I type

```
a=0.00001;
IntegerPart[a/a]
```

and well, the output is 0.

Try with almost any other value of `a`, say `a=0.01`, and the result is correctly 1. I did some trials and I found that it fails again with `a=0.000000001`. I also found that a possible fix is

```
a=0.00001 // Rationalize;
```

(then I got tired).
What is going on?
Can this have to do with the MachinePrecision?

More in general, how do I fix it once and for all for the entire Notebook?

Comment: RealDigits[a/a] => {{9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 0}
In the memory this is a number less than 1. Yes it has to do with machine epsilon

Comment: Also interesting example: 

arr = RandomReal[1, 100000];
Tally[RealDigits /@ (arr/arr)] => 
{{{{9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 0}, 
  15338}, {{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 1}, 
  84662}}. ~15% numbers giving not 1 when you try to divide number on itself

Comment: Try `IntegerPart[Divide[a, a]]`. It has been noted before on this site that "a / a" is parsed as `Times[a, Power[a, -1]]`. The roundoff error in ``1 / a = 99999.99999999999`` means `a * (1/a)` does not cancel (and sometimes doesn't for other values of `a`).

Comment: Try to change precision by hand: a = 0.00001`16;
IntegerPart[a/a] => 1. Also you can use SetPrecision

Comment: @KirillBelov You might be interested in this: ``Table[a = 10.`16^-k; IntegerPart[a/a], {k, 100}]``. The use of arbitrary-precision means more bits than in machine precision are used to represent the floating-point numbers (plus precision tracking, which is unimportant here). All the extra precision does is change where the problem occurs.

Comment: Yes @MichaelE2, I had exactly the same feeling

Comment: See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45178) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39200).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [H]ow do I fix it once and for all for the entire Notebook?

I suppose it depends on how you want to treat results that contain round-off error. You cannot really get rid of the problem, only shift where the problem arises. For instance, in `IntegerPart[x]`, `IntegerPart` (nor usually the program/programmer) knows at that point whether the roundoff error that led to `x` is positive, negative, or zero. If you fix `IntegerPart[x]` when `x` comes from `a/a` and is one bit less than `1.`, then it will be broken when another `x` has a roundoff error that increases it to one bit less than `1.`. One may be willing to live with it being broken in this way.  Here's a way based on `Equal` comparing with tolerance:

```
intPart // ClearAll;
intPart[x_?NumericQ] /; x == Round[x] := Round[x];
intPart[x_?NumericQ] := IntegerPart[x];

intPart[a/a]
(*  1  *)
```

Make it `Listable` if your code relies on `IntegerPart` being listable. You can change the tolerance used by `Equal` with `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``.

Another approach is to "correct" real numbers that are close to integers:

```
snapToInteger // ClearAll;
snapToInteger[expr_] := 
 expr /. {x_Real /; x == Round[x] :> 
    SetPrecision[Round[x], Precision[x]]};

IntegerPart[snapToInteger[a/a]]
(*  1  *)
```

Either approach is likely to incur a performance hit, which may or may not be important.

For what it's worth, this works on `x = a/a`, because of the nature of the rounding error and how `MatchQ` works on machine reals and bignums, and it's a bit faster:

```
intPart // ClearAll;
intPart[x_Real] /; MatchQ[x, N[Round[x], Precision[x]] := 
  Round[x];
intPart[x_?NumericQ] := IntegerPart[x];
```

Comment: I have to say that using `Divide[a/a]`, as you suggested under my question, is also (often) a quick and valid fix.

Comment: @DavideVenturelli You may have noticed that if `x` is a symbol (without a numeric or other value), `Divide[x, x]` evaluates to `x/x`, that is, `Times[x, Power[x, -1]]`. Sometimes it's not so easy to replace `/` by `Divide[]`, and since there was no response to my comment, I thought it might not work in all your use-cases.