# ImageType used by ImageData

Tags: image

I have an image of type `"Byte"` (from `ImageType[image]`). When I perform calculations with `ImageData[image]` (like `Total[ImageData[image]]`) are these calculations still performed with the `"Byte"` data format or conversion into another format like `Integer` or `Real` is performed under the hood?

Comment: `Total[ ]` will add up numbers the usual way in Mathematica, notwithstanding where they come from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ImageType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageType.html)s `"Bit"`, `"Byte"` and `"Bit16"` correspond to images encoded by 1-bit, 8-bit and 16-bit unsigned integers, images of types `"Real32"` and `"Real"` are encoded by single- (32-bit) and double-precision (64-bit) real numbers correspondingly.

According to the Documentation page for `ImageType` (under the "Backgound" section):

> Many image processing functions automatically convert integer-type
>   images to a real type for higher accuracy prior to computation.

So in general image-processing function may convert images into `"Real32"` or `"Real"` type for processing. Under the "Details and Options" section on the Documentation page for `ImageData` we read:

> For images of type `"Byte"` or `"Bit16"`, `ImageData[image]` always
>   normalizes values to lie between 0 and 1.

This statement is ambiguous because it is not clear whether the channel values are rescaled to run from 0 to 1 or they are simply converted into a real type via dividing by `255` (for `"Byte"`) or `65535` (for `"Bit16"`). It is also not clear which real type is the target: `"Real"` or `"Real32"`.

Let us investigate. For this purpose we generate an image of type `"Byte"` where channel values run from `100` to `200` (the full allowed range is from `0` to `255`):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[{100, 200}, {125, 325, 3}];
i = Image[data, "Byte"]
ImageType[i]
```

> [image]
>
> ```
> "Byte"
> ```

Now we check what `ImageData` returns:

```
Head@ImageData[i][[1, 1, 1]]
MinMax[ImageData[i]]
% * 255
```

> ```
> Real
>
> {0.392157, 0.784314}
>
> {100., 200.}
> ```

We see that `ImageData` by default converts the channel values of images of type `"Byte"` into `Real` numbers between `0` and `1` without rescaling. To prevent the conversion we need to specify the `Automatic` type of image:

> `ImageData[image, Automatic]` is equivalent to
>   `ImageData[image, ImageType[image]]`.

Checking:

```
Head@ImageData[i, Automatic][[1, 1]]
MinMax[ImageData[i, Automatic]]
```

> ```
> Integer
>
> {100, 200}
> ```

Let us ensure that the original image data are converted into `"Real"` type, not `"Real32"`:

```
Max[Abs[ImageData[i, Automatic]/255. - ImageData[i]]]
```

> ```
> 1.11022*10^-16
> ```

This difference corresponds to `MachinePrecision` computations:

```
10^-$MachinePrecision
```

> ```
> 1.11022*10^-16
> ```

So the channel values are converted from `"Byte"` into `Real` numbers with `MachinePrecision`. Let us try another conversion method:

```
Max[Abs[Divide[ImageData[i, Automatic], 255.] - ImageData[i]]]
```

> ```
> 0.`
> ```

With this last method the difference is explicitly zero, so `ImageData` seems to use [the intelligent `Divide`-based approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39200/280) for the data conversion.

---

Another thing which is worth to know is that `ImageData` by default has `Interleaving -> True`:

```
ImageData // Options
```

> ```
> {DataReversed -> False, Interleaving -> True}
> ```

This means that `ImageData` by default returns interleaved data even for images without interleaving:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 5}];
image = Image[data, Interleaving -> False];
ImageData[image, Interleaving -> False] == data == Transpose[ImageData[image], {2, 3, 1}]
Transpose[data, {3, 1, 2}] == ImageData[image]
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
> ```

---

And a little aside from the main topic but still worth to cite here a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141231/import-image-saved-as-csv-file/141235?noredirect=1#comment381641_141235) by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs):

> Unfortunately the documentation does not spell this out, but `Real` and
>   `"Real32"` (i.e. floating point) types do not clip in `Image`. Integer
>   pixel types do clip. It is unfortunate that this is not made clear in
>   the documentation because it is one of the first things that is
>   explained on WRI image processing seminars ...
>
> ˂The Documentation for `Image`˃ says that values are displayed from 0 to
>   1, but it does not say that greater or smaller values are not stored.
>   It says that values are coerced to the target type. This coercion
>   necessitates clipping with integer types, but not (usually) with
>   floating point type (unless you go above ~10^300). The same with
>   rounding. Basically it says that M does whatever is needed to fit the
>   value into the target type.

Here are the corresponding statements under the "Details and Options" section of the Documentation page for [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html):

> - `Image[data]` by default allows any real number, but displays only values between 0 and 1.
> - `Image[data,"type"]` can be used to create an image of a specified data type. Values in `data` are coerced to the specified type by rounding or clipping. By default, `"Real"` is assumed.

Checking:

```
ImageData[Image[{{-10, 0, 1, 100}}], Automatic]
ImageData[Image[{{-10, 0, 255, 1000}}, "Byte"], Automatic]
ImageData[Image[{{-10, 0, 65535, 100000}}, "Bit16"], Automatic]
```

> ```
> {{-10., 0., 1., 100.}}
>
> {{0, 0, 255, 255}}
>
> {{0, 0, 65535, 65535}}
> ```

Conversion to `Raster` and backwards:

```
Show[Image[{{-10, 0, 1, 100}}]][[1, 1]] // Normal
```

> ```
> {{-10., 0., 1., 100.}}
> ```

```
ImageData@Image@Show[Image[{{-10, 0, 1, 100}}]][[1]]
```

> ```
> {{-10., 0., 1., 100.}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [its documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html), you can specify what format `ImageData` should use to return its output. Let's use your avatar as an example:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m6HE.jpg?s=328&g=1"];

ImageType[img]                       (*Out: Byte        *)

Total[ImageData[img, "Byte"], -1]    (*Out: 42543966    *)
Total[ImageData[img, "Bit16"], -1]   (*Out: 10933799262 *)
Total[ImageData[img, "Real32"], -1]  (*Out: 166839.     *)
```

As a further example, you can inspect the different ways a pixel's color values are reported:

```
ImageData[img, "Byte"][[150, 150]]    (*Out: {75, 77, 74}                   *)
ImageData[img, "Bit16"][[150, 150]]   (*Out: {19275, 19789, 19018}          *)
ImageData[img, "Real32"][[150, 150]]  (*Out: {0.294118, 0.301961, 0.290196} *)
```

Comment: So what is Total[ImageData[img],2] by default ?