# ImageData to Image conversion

Tags: image-processing, image

I assumed that `Image` and `ImageData` are inverses, so that the following expression gives back the original image.

```
Image[ImageData[image]]
```

But that doesn't work. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? `Image[ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]]]` works fine...

Comment: Actually `Image[ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]]] == 
 ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]` returns false.  If you look at `FullForm` you see the image color representation has changed from interger to float.

Comment: If you use for example a black 24-bit Bitmap image, then what you will get back is a blue image.

Comment: I colud have sworn this is a duplicate or at least thoroughly discussed in another question but can't find it.

Comment: Strongly related: "[`ImageType` used by `ImageData`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87936/280)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would guess it's something to do with the [`ImageType`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageType.html).

```
img1 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
img2 = Image[ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]]];    
img1 == img2
(* False *)
ImageType[img1]
(* Byte *)    
ImageType[img2]
(* Real *)
```

However, trying the following doesn't seem to help:

```
img3 = Image[
   ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], "Byte"], "Byte"];
ImageType[img3]
(* Byte *)    
img3 == img1
(* False *)
```

---

But the following (courtesy of [@george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079)) does work! It must be related to the default option for [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html) being the following, rather than RGB, so the original colorspace is not preserved.

> `ColorSpace -> Automatic` treats values as arbitrary channel intensities

```
img4 = Image[
  ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], "Byte"], "Byte", 
  ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
img1 == img4
(* True *)
```

Hence the following code from [@Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) should work generally:

```
Image[ImageData[#, ImageType[#]], ImageType[#], Options[#]] &[img1]
```

Comment: puzzled myself.. this gets it back: `Image[ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}],   "Byte"], "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB"]`

Comment: probably more general: `img1 === Image[ImageData[#, ImageType[#]], ImageType[#], 
    Options[#]] &[img1]`

Comment: Shouldn't the ColorSpace of RGB provide only 3 parameters? A black bmp image mentioned above comes with a `ColorSpace` of RGB, but the `ImageData` looks like `{{0,0,0,255},{0,0,0,255}...}`. What does the 4th parameter do?

Comment: @AntonAlice It denotes the transparency, or "alpha" value.