# Import image saved as CSV file

Tags: import, image, csv-format

I have saved my image file from ccd camera as a CSV file. How can I plot this file to get my image back? My file is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwrukO4XMWygUEZQS3YwRjFvWGc).

Comment: Could you provide a ASCII file for test?

Comment: @yode https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwrukO4XMWygUEZQS3YwRjFvWGc

Comment: You may be wondering why this question got downvotes.  Think about how the original version reads. It was simply "*I have saved my image file from ccd camera as ASCII file. How can I plot this file to get my image back?*".  There was no link to the file, no explanation of the file format, and most importantly, no evidence that you made an attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking. Have you tried searching the documentation for "CSV" to see how to import this format?

Comment: [It is important to be aware that StackExchange is not a discussion forum.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)  Questions should be asked in such a way to make them answerable without a lot of back and forth about what you really need. If you expect to get clarification questions, then the post is inappropriate.

Comment: Related docs that answer your question: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html

Comment: Strongly related WC thread: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1211427

Answer (score 6):

*Mathematica* is a toy more than a real tool for me, I'm glad to see you need it in your life. And I'm sorry you got those downvotes. In your case, you just:

```
data = Import["D:\\Downloads\\Idler_T_62_0001.ascii.csv"];
img=Image[Rescale[Most /@ data]]
```

[image]

You can save your image into your desktop by this code.

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory,"\\Desktop","restore.png"}],img]
```

Comment: Use `Rescale` to avoid clipping:  `Image[Rescale[Most /@ data], "Real"]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks very much,I have updated that. :)

Comment: @yode Thanks, If i have to save this image in rgb format then what should i add?

Comment: @Varunsharma See the update.And if the answer have helped you,you can click [this mark](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/29/58db724c9bf0e.jpg) to accept it for this question.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm confusing still.Since I have used `"Real"` or `"Real32"`.I think it should not be clipped..

Comment: @yode I am able to save file but if I want to give color map to this image then what should I do?

Comment: @yode Intensity values for `"Real"` images are from `0` to `1`. Read the Docs for `Image`: "`Image[data,"type"]` can be used to create an image of a specified data type. Values in `data` are coerced to the specified type by rounding or clipping."

Comment: @Varunsharma Well nobody expected a endless query in one post.As your request,you can try this `Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> #] & /@ 
 RandomSample[ColorData["Gradients"], 3]`

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Unfortunately the documentation does not spell this out, but `Real` and `"Real32"` (i.e. floating point) types do not clip in `Image`.  Integer pixel types do clip.  It is unfortunate that this is not made clear in the documentation because it is one of the first things that is explained on WRI image processing seminars ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you. So we have a bug in the Docs (see the citation [above](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141231/plotiing-of-the-ascii-file/141235?noredirect=1#comment381637_141235))?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov In my opinion, the description is accurate, but I do see why it is confusing, and I just submitted a suggestion to improve it. It says that values are displayed from 0..1, but it does not say that greater or smaller value are not stored. It says that values are coerced to the target type.  This coercion necessitates clipping with integer types, but not (usually) with floating point type (unless you go above ~10^300). The same with rounding. Basically it says that M does whatever is needed to fit the value into the target type.

Comment: So do you "toy around with tools" or "tool around with toys"? (Sorry, couldn't help it) :) - (+1) for the answer.