# Why is C-compiled (but not WVM-compiled) code so slow in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, compile, performance-tuning

Here is a small section of code from [this SE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61844/fine-tuning-compiled-code-that-computes-dilogarithm-function) which computes the real part of the dilogarithm (the upper limit of the sum is increased for demonstration purposes):

```
realRegion1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sum[x^k/k^2, {k, 1., 1000}]];
```

Here is the performance when compiled to the Wolfram Virtual Machine (WVM):

```
(* to WVM *)
Timing[Table[realRegion1[x], {x, -.9, .9, .001}];]
```

> {0.260303, Null}

and the performance when compiled to C (which I get by running `$CompilationTarget = "C"` *before* running the `realRegion1` code):

```
(*to C*)
Timing[Table[realRegion1[x], {x, -.9, .9, .001}];]
```

> {0.096413, Null}

Now I run into a **big problem** when I pass the compiled function `realRegion1[x]` to `Manipulate`.  As an example, try

```
Manipulate[Plot[realRegion1[a x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 2.0}], {{a, 1}, .1, 1}]
```

If the function was complied to WVM, the controls are as slick as butter.  But, if the function was compiled to C, they are *very* unresponsive.  I am upset.

How do I understand/alleviate this sluggishness when compiled to C?

I am using Mathematica 9.0.1 on Mac OSX.

Comment: Very likely because you're passing symbolic arguments to the function (`a x`).  Try `Evaluated -> False` in `Plot`.

Comment: Quite interesting. The reason is exactly your special setting `$CompilationTarget = "C"`, and the problem won't appear if `CompilationTarget -> "C"` is used! Don't why though……BTW, the solution from @Szabolcs also works.

Comment: @Szabolcs Setting the option `Evaluated->False` does make it more responsive.  I'm trying to find more info on this option, but the documentation doesn't seem to exist.  Do you know where I can find more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve that problem adding a function with a pattern in the argument. Try:

```
realRegion1a[x_Real] := realRegion1[x]
```

And the try your `Manipulate` using that new function. It will behave as expected.

Comment: This seems not to work, at least on v8.0.4, vista 32bit.

Comment: I don't have anymore M8, so cannot test there, but tested it in 9 and 10 and worked fine.

Comment: This solution appears to work in 9.0.1 MacOSX and in 10.0.1 on Linux.