# When to use WVM instead of C for CompilationTarget?

Tags: compile

In which cases is it advantageous to compile using the Wolfram Virtual Machine (`"WVM"`) option rather than the C Code (`"C"`) for `CompilationTarget` when using `Compile`?

Some questions on this site point to differences in [memory usage](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92178/memory-usage-of-compiled-function-c-vs-wvm), [performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69266/why-is-c-compiled-but-not-wvm-compiled-code-so-slow-in-manipulate), [compilation speed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88899/compilationtarget-to-c-takes-long-compilation-time) in certain cases. Besides that, there is a known [list of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions). Is WVM also limited to those?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IMHO, the only feasible usage cases of `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` I can image are:

- You work on a device without a *C* compiler (e.g., when you just don't have the rights to install one).
- You want/have to leave the list `` Compile`CompilerFunctions[] `` of compilable functions for some reason. Then calling `` CompiledFunctionTool`CompilePrint `` on the `CompiledFunction` might reveal occurences of `MainEvaluate` in the pseudocode. A couple of times I have run into situations where the communication between the *Wolfram Virtual Machine* and the *Mathematica* Kernel was faster than between the library compiled from *C* and the *Mathematica* Kernel. But in most of these cases, when speed was important, I used *LibraryLink* to write a fully fleshed *C++* program with the same capabilities. And the runtimes were always considerably faster than with `"WVM"`.
- Sometimes, `"WVM"` is also faster in calling precompiled functions like `Dot` many times on small matrices or vectors. But again, using *LibraryLink* to either call the correct BLAS routines or simply writing out the loops with trip counts known at compile time will speed up everything way more than `Compile` with `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"`.

Some people might argue that the compilation times with `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` are shorter. My point of view on this is that if you cannot ammortize the compilation time of `CompilationTarget -> "C"` vs. `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"`, then you simply have a task that is not worth compilation in the first place. But of course, there may be exceptions to this.

Generally, `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` seems to produce slower code. Using `CompilationTarget -> "C"` will force a mighty *C* compiler to look at your code and optimize (or at least improve it) it (for your hardware).
So in summary, I recommend to consider `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` merely as a fallback in case of the absence of a working *C* compiler. Personally, I almost never use it.

**Edit: One of the few(?) exceptions**

Okay, here is the *one* killer application that I found for `"WVM"`: Threading operations like `Dot` over tensors. The key point is the option `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` and that we call the function `Dot` that has a very efficient, compiled backend. Moreover, with `Parallelization -> True` it also allows for some parallelization (which, unfortunately, does not scale particularly well).

Here the code for several threaded versions of `Dot`.

```
ClearAll[TensorDotThreadWVM];
TensorDotThreadWVM[rankA_Integer, rankB_Integer] := 
  Compile[{{A, _Real, rankA}, {B, _Real, rankB}},
   A . B,
   CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

ClearAll[TensorDotThreadWVMMemoized];
TensorDotThreadWVMMemoized[rankA_Integer, rankB_Integer] := 
  TensorDotThreadWVMMemoized[rankA, rankB] = 
   Compile[{{A, _Real, rankA}, {B, _Real, rankB}},
    A . B,
    CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ];


ClearAll[TensorDotThreadC];
TensorDotThreadC[rankA_Integer, rankB_Integer] := 
  Compile[{{A, _Real, rankA}, {B, _Real, rankB}},
   A . B,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

ClearAll[TensorDotThreadCMemoized];
TensorDotThreadCMemoized[rankA_Integer, rankB_Integer] := 
  TensorDotThreadCMemoized[rankA, rankB] = 
   Compile[{{A, _Real, rankA}, {B, _Real, rankB}},
    A . B,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ];
```

For example, suppose we are given many, many matrices (rank $= 2$) of size `{m1,m2}` stored in some high rank *packed array* `A` and many, many matrices (rank $= 2$) of size `{m2,m3}` stored in some high rank *packed array* `B` like so:

```
n = 1000;
m1 = 12;
m2 = 8;
m3 = 11;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n, m1, m2}];
B = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n, m2, m3}];
```

Now, we want to multiply each matrix in `A` with each corresponding matrix in `B` like so:

```
result = MapThread[Dot, {A, B}, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.28851

Here are 4 alternatives to do the same:

```
resultWVM = TensorDotThreadWVM[2, 2][A, B]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
resultWVMMemoized = TensorDotThreadWVMMemoized[2, 2][A, B]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
resultC = TensorDotThreadC[2, 2][A, B]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
resultCMemoized = TensorDotThreadCMemoized[2, 2][A, B]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.154104
>
> 0.151299
>
> 0.600961
>
> 0.536399

Obviously, the two version that use `CompilationTarget -> "C"` are slower because of the compilation cost.

I am pretty sure that each of these methods calls the same BLAS routine `blas_dgemm` (or `cblas_dgemm`); otherwise the results would unlikely coincide *bitwise*:

```
Max[Abs[result - resultWVM]]
Max[Abs[result - resultWVMMemoized]]
Max[Abs[result - resultC]]
Max[Abs[result - resultCMemoized]]
```

> 0. 

> 0. 

> 0. 

> 0. 

`TensorDotThreadCMemoized` is memoized, i.e., the created `CompiledFunction` is stored and when it is called the next time:

So let's run this again (and let's measure time with RepeatedTiming):

```
result = MapThread[Dot, {A, B}, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
resultWVM = TensorDotThreadWVM[2, 2][A, B]; // RepeatedTiming // First
resultWVMMemoized = TensorDotThreadWVMMemoized[2, 2][A, B]; // RepeatedTiming // First
resultC = TensorDotThreadC[2, 2][A, B]; // RepeatedTiming // First
resultCMemoized = TensorDotThreadCMemoized[2, 2][A, B]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 1.22665
>
> 0.172471
>
> 0.171726
>
> 0.326404
>
> 0.181896

Now we finally see that the `TensorDotThreadWVM` has already so little overhead, (i) that it is neither worth to memoize it and (ii) that compiling into a library does not help (or might even be slightly counterproductive).

Comment: "But of course, there may be exceptions to this." There probably are. I guess functions which auto-compile (e.g. `Table`) use the WVM for this reason. Compilation times can be very noticeably long on Windows. But something as advanced as auto-compilation would be a very small fraction of use-cases for users (as opposed to package developers).

Comment: Yeah. My thought is also that a package developer is typically willing to invest some more development time to squeeze out a good runtime for their users. So they would probably move large parts of the code to the _C/C++_ side anyways. At least that's what I do all the time (for this reason and because it is often quite cumbersome to penetrate that many layers of abstraction).

Comment: The only time I WVM compilation is a good choice is for on-the-fly compilation of fire-and-forget functions. Basically like what Map and Table do. It usually doesn't speed things up dramatically, but it's not going to unexpectedly slow things down a whole lot either.