# What is a good way to code long, complex, compilable algorithms?

Tags: syntax, compile, coding-style

The functional paradigm of the Wolfram Language used in *Mathematica* is all around wonderful.

For intense numerics, *Mathematica* comes with the ability to `Compile` sections of code to the *Wolfram Virtual Machine* (WVM).  When written correctly, this can lead to speed boosts by orders of magnitude (I am particularly proud of the code in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61844/fine-tuning-compiled-code-that-computes-dilogarithm-function) that computes the Dilogarithm).  Also, it is totally portable, which makes it particularly useful to include in packages for public use.

But, for extremely long and complex algorithms, it is agonizingly clumsy to write the procedural code in *Mathematica*'s functional syntax.  Especially bad is if there are lots of nested `If` statements, and multiple subroutines that tend to require `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}`.  All the `[[ [ [ [[`  and `]] ] ] ]]` drive me totally crazy.

Is there a way to write code that is closer in syntax to *C* that can also compile to WVM to preserve the overall portability?

Comment: I try to modify individual functions for each if statement, but sometimes it becomes messy when the if statements need lots of arguments.

Comment: I also try to use the prefix form to reduce the number of [ ] but you are right, it can be a pain sometimes...

Comment: I'd disagree with the "opinion-based" close reason. Although a possible answer to this *is* opinion-based, I don't think this is a bad thing in this case. Such answers, opinion-based or not, will likely be useful.

Comment: Since I wrote this question, I found out that `Which` is compilable, and really helps cut down on nested `If` statements.