# Does Compilation option "InlineExternalDefinitions"/"InlineCompiledFunctions" lead to unnecessarily complicated nesting?

Tags: function-construction, compile

**Question:**  When an external (possibly complicated) definition `f` is used inside a compiled function with `CompilationOption->{"InlineCompiledFunctions"->True}`, does *Mathematica* really store the resulting code with every single instance of `f` replaced with its explicit definition *inlined* as the name of the option suggests?

For example, consider the compiled implementation of the following formula:

$f(x,a,b,c) = \text{Re }\text{Li}_2\big(\frac{(x-b^2+a^2)(a^2-c^2)}{x a^2-(b^2-a^2)(a^2-c^2)}\big) - \text{Re }\text{Li}_2\big(\frac{-(b^2-a^2)(a^2-c^2)}{x a^2-(b^2-a^2)(a^2-c^2)}\big)$

where $\text{Re }\text{Li}_2$ is the real part of the dilogarithm, whose compiled implementation is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61844/fine-tuning-compiled-code-that-computes-dilogarithm-function).  Now inspecting the result of compiling this secondary function,

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {c, _Real}}, 
    reLi2[((x - b^2 + a^2) (a^2 - c^2))/(x a^2 - (b^2 - a^2) (a^2 - c^2))]
     - reLi2[(-(b^2 - a^2) (a^2 - c^2))/(x a^2 - (b^2 - a^2) (a^2 - c^2))], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

it seems to me that indeed the way *Mathematica* stores the compiled result is by replacing both instances of `reLi2` in `f` by the entire algorithm.  Does this not require an excessive amount of memory to store such functions?  Indeed, on my computer, it seems that it requires a whopping 1 MB to store this simple function:

```
ByteCount[f]
```

> 1 361 192

**Follow up question:**  If this is the case, is it possible to compile functions such that outside definitions are compiled as *subroutines*, so that it requires less memory?  It seems the most logical way to compile more complicated functions.

Comment: You can inspect the compiled function `f` with `CompilePrint` and see how it behaves.