# Improve inverted 3D Truchet tiling?

Tags: code-review, generative-art

Here is a 3D inverted Truchet tiling, `p` is "radius of the tubes", `n` is "volume".

```
    inverze[x_] := 8 x/(x[[1]]^2 + x[[2]]^2 + x[[3]]^2) ;
    p = 0.3;
    n = 4;
    nrotace = 
    Table[RandomInteger[3], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {r, 1, n}];
    nzrcadleni = 
    Table[RandomInteger[1], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {r, 1, n}];
    mat = Table[(If[nzrcadleni[[i, j, k, 3]] == 1, 
    ReflectionMatrix[{1, 0, 0}], IdentityMatrix[3]]).(If[
    nzrcadleni[[i, j, k, 2]] == 1, ReflectionMatrix[{0, 1, 0}], 
    IdentityMatrix[3]]).(If[nzrcadleni[[i, j, k, 1]] == 1, 
    ReflectionMatrix[{0, 0, 1}], IdentityMatrix[3]]).RotationMatrix[
    nrotace[[i, j, k, 1]] (Pi/2), {0, 0, 1}].RotationMatrix[
    nrotace[[i, j, k, 2]] (Pi/2), {0, 1, 0}].RotationMatrix[
    nrotace[[i, j, k, 3]] (Pi/2), {1, 0, 0}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}];
    tst = Table[2 {i - (n + 1)/2, j - (n + 1)/2, k - (n + 1)/2} + (mat[[i, j, k]].#) & /@ {{(1 + p Cos[v]) Cos[u] - 1, (1 + p Cos[v]) Sin[u] - 1, p Sin[v]}, {(1 + p Cos[v]) Sin[u + (3/2) Pi] + 1, p Sin[v], (1 + p Cos[v]) Cos[u + (3/2) Pi] - 1}, {p Sin[v], (1 + p Cos[v]) Sin[u + Pi] + 1, (1 + p Cos[v]) Cos[u + Pi] + 1}}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}];
    tst2 = (inverze /@ Flatten[tst, 3]);
    ParametricPlot3D[tst2, {u, 0, Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, PlotStyle -> {Red,Specularity[White, 20]}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 5^2], ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, SphericalRegion -> True, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

**Result**
[image]

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41Nwmj2rxPY) is what it looks like when it is ray traced:

You can also change continuously the point of inversion to make some nice videos.  Please suggest useful code optimizations.

Comment: Here is the effect of the continuous change of the point of inversion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QWqqTdT8Kg

Comment: OK, my mistake, so delete it please.

Comment: This may be a very interesting topic, but as posted, it is not appropriate for this site because there is no question about Mathematica.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it poses no question that is appropriate to this site.

Comment: I can't delete it, but you can.

Comment: I don't know how. Wait. :)

Comment: I'd like to see this code remain available on SE.  Maybe editing the question would be a better approach than removal.

Comment: Could you explain a bit the details of your code or of how the image is generated, to help us improve it? You could start by defining `nrotace` and `nzrcadleni` with `nrotace = RandomInteger[3, {n, n, n, n}];
nzrcadleni = RandomInteger[1, {n, n, n, n}];` or, shorter,  `{nrotace, nzrcadleni} = RandomInteger[#, {n, n, n, n}] & /@ {3, 1};`.

Comment: If you simply would like to showcase your code and model you can post at [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com) where question format is not required.

Comment: Try to write your question like [in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61844/fine-tuning-compiled-code-that-computes-dilogarithm-function).  Show what each part of the code does, and suggest where you think the code could use some optimizations.