# Increasing the zero threshold

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I have a function similar to this:

```
func[x_]:=Log[1+x]
```

when I evaluate it at very small arguments, it will become 0, i.e.

```
func[1.0*10^-20]
0.
```

Looks like this transition to zero happens when the output is smaller than `10^-16` (zero threshold). As I need to integrate this `func` multiplied by something that can range up to `10^90`, I'd like to make the zero threshold to be atleast at `10^-100`. How to accomplish this?

(Currently, `func[1.0*10^-20]*10^90` outputs `0`, but the real value is `10^70`)

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39126)?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Seems like the second answer from there, which gave `log1p[x_Real] := With[{w = 1 + x}, If[w-1 == 0, x, x*Log@w/(w-1)]]` works just as I wanted + is more accurate. Thanks.