# Round off in Mathematica Built-in functions

Tags: numerics, special-functions

Is there a way to force Mathematica to use its Built-in functions instead basic functions?

For instance, the Hypergeometric1F1[a,b,x] function has a exponential form when its firsts parameters are integers. Mathematica replace for the exponential form automatically. For example,

```
Hypergeometric1F1[1,2,x]
```

[image: Hypergeometric1F1[1,2,x] -> (-1 + E^x)/x]

the Hypergeometric1F1[1,2,x] is transformed in (-1 + E^x)/x. It is a problem if you want to evaluate numerically for x near to 0, because the exponential form has round-off errors.

One way to avoid this problem is using delayed definitions, which evaluates the built-in functions before its replacement. But it is not enough if you want to use this functions in different operations, like differentiating, before evaluate it.

```
f[x_]:=Hypergeometric[1,2,x]
g[x_]=Hypergeometric[1,2,x]
```

The map f[x] will use the Build-in function in Mathematica, but g[x] will not. But if you differentiate both functions, you'll get the exponential form:

```
D[f[x],x] 
D[g[x],x]
```

The result will be

```
-((-1 + E^x)/x^2) + E^x/x
```

Instead of

```
(1/2)*Hypergeometric1F1[2, 3, x]
```

I want to force Mathematica use its Hypergeometric Build-in function, but I don't know how.

Comment: There are many, many things about *Mathematica* that I don't understand.  If one just uses `LogLogPlot[Hypergeometric1F1[1, 2, x], {x, 10^(-15), 10^(-5)}]`, it plots just fine.

Comment: WorkingPrecision is a MUCH easier fix for plots with roundoff problems. LogLogPlot[{(-1+E^x)/x, Hypergeometric1F1[1,2,x]+10^-6}, {x,10^-15,10^-5}, WorkingPrecision->64, PlotRange->All] (I slightly vertically offset one plot so that you can see they are the same and not wonder why you only see one plot, perhaps because of PlotRange or because of having complex values.)

Comment: @Bill: Why does increasing the `WorkingPrecision` result in values around 2.718 rather than 1.0 ?

Comment: @JimBaldwin - `LogLogPlot` has attribute `HoldAll` so the `Hypergeometric1F1` does not get simplified prior to its numerical evaluation. The OP's plot command is equivalent to `LogLogPlot[{Evaluate[Hypergeometric1F1[1, 2, x]], 
  Hypergeometric1F1[1, 2, x]}, {x, 10^(-15), 10^(-5)}]`

Comment: @JimBaldwin the `WorkingPrecsion` issue with log scales is a known bug : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15628/2079 .  I think that's unrelated to this particular question though.

Comment: Thanks, @george2079.  I got it now.  The "wrong" value (around 2.718) is produced when `WorkingPrecision` is invoked which should more correctly be around 1.0 (approximately `Log[2.718]`).

Comment: Perhaps using NumericQ like I did here, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39126/elegant-high-precision-log1p/85413#85413, for the same reason, might help

Comment: Better to post actual code instead of images of code. Nobody likes to rekey input by hand.

Comment: It's too bad `D[Inactive[Hypergeometric1F1][a, b, x], x]` doesn't quite work.