# Exp[x] answers 1 for small x

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I'm getting the same answer "1" for Exp[x] with x less than "1.1*10^-16", and I really need to calculate much smaller numbers (in order of 10^-40).

I tried using SetPrecision[Exp[x],1000].

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. #_-

I've searched about increasing the precision but I couldn't find helpful answers. Would you please kindly guide me?

**Edit:**

Maybe this screenshot could make it easier to understand what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: Try `N[Exp[11/10000000000000000000000], 4000]`.  In other words, use rational numbers and not numbers with decimal points when you need lots of precision.

Comment: By default only 6 digits are displayed, see Preferences -> Appearance -> Numbers -> Displayed precision. Edit the output cell to see all.  In your last examples first you compute something ridiculously close to 1 using machine precision (15 digits), and only after you get the result you increase the precision ...

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick replies. I've tried them. @JimBaldwin I have other calculations that results to "x" which is not rational. Like divisions and stuff. I think I'm going to lose accuracy If I Rationalize my "x" right?

Comment: Most languages' standard libraries provide an `expm1` function for this purpose, which returns $\exp(x)-1$ to high precision even when $\exp(x)$ would return exactly $1$. Mathematica unfortunately doesn't, but if that's your goal, you could implement something similar [along the lines of `log1p`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39126/484).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting the precision too late.

```
Exp[1.`200*^-40]
```

and

```
Exp[SetPrecision[1*^-40, 200]]
```

yield

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On the other hand,

```
SetPrecision[Exp[1.*^-40], 200]
```

yields

[image: Mathematica graphics]

because `Exp[1.*^-40]` evaluates to `1.` (exactly, in machine precision), before it is passed to `SetPrecision`.

Comment: Woah Thanks! You made my day!

Comment: @PedramAshofteArdakani You're welcome.

Comment: Hi again! I noticed something strange here, Exp[SetPrecision `[1.1^-40, 200]]` , `Exp[(1.1\`200)^-40]` and `Exp[(SetPrecision[1.1, 200])^-40]` Hold different answers, aren't these supposed to be identical?

Comment: @PedramAshofteArdakani I don't think they supposed to be identical. `1.1^40` is first computed in 16-digit machine precision and will have significant differences when compared to the other 200-digit precision results. For the difference in the other two, examine ``1.1`200 // FullForm`` and ``SetPrecision[1.1, 200] // FullForm``. Here the difference arises because ``1.1`200`` is *parsed* to have 200-digit precision, whereas with `SetPrecision`, the `1.1` is first evaluated at 16-digit machine precision, then converted to 200-digit precision.