# Multivariate function won't evaluate

Tags: functions, evaluation

When I define the following variables and function and then evaluate that function at given values:

```
c = 3*10^10;
k = 1.381*10^-16;
h = 6.626*10^-27;

g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_] = (2*h*c^2)/(x2^5*x6)*(x3 + x4*x1 + x5/2*x1^2)^-1 + 1.

g[0.2, 3737, 0.1435, 0.9481, -0.0920, 42.0*10^13]
```

I get the following output:

```
1. + 0.0000119268/(x2^5 (x3 + x1 x4 + (x1^2 x5)/2) x6)

1.
```

I tried a simpler function to see if I get the same output and I did. I entered the following:

```
h1[x_, y_] = Log[x + y];
h1[1, 1]
```

which yielded `Log[2]`

What is going on here?

Comment: Welcome to the forum! There are some fundamental differences in how the Wolfram Language works compared to other languages that you may already be familiar with. I suggest that you read the guides here, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html, and here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html.

Comment: Please note that it is not equal to 1, `Rationalize[g[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 0]==62255051/62254754`

Comment: Welcome to Mma SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour), 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: And an added comment, these numbers are a bit familiar. They remind me of quantum mechanics stuff or quantum field theory stuff. Should that be the case, you can also work in [Natural Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Systems_of_natural_units) and make your life easier with the constants

Comment: What is the different result you were expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what's going on, I think I have understood the question of the OP correctly, I think it's educational to do the computation step by step, while keeping in mind the comment by @cvgmt.

If you sub in all the values except for the `x6` you have the following:

```
((2*h*c^2)/(x2^5*x6)*(x3 + x4*x1 + x5/2*x1^2)^-1 + 1.) /. 
      x1 -> 0.2 /. x2 -> 3737 /. x3 -> 0.1435 /. x4 -> 0.9481 /. 
  x5 -> -0.0920 // Rationalize
```

> `1 + 4.93984*10^-23/x6`

Now, if we check

```
4.939843951797836`*^-23/x6 /. x6 -> (42.0*10^13)
```

we get

> `1.17615*10^-37`

So, we want Mathematica to keep this and not `Chop` it to zero.

Borrowing the code from the [wondeful answer by kirma](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189857/how-to-display-very-small-numbers-in-mathematica/189865)

```
ClearAll@RationalizedN;
SetAttributes[RationalizedN, HoldFirst];
RationalizedN[expr_, n_: $MachinePrecision] := 
  N[FixedPoint[
    ReleaseHold@*
     ReplaceAll[
      x_ :> RuleCondition[Hold@Evaluate@Rationalize[x, 0], 
        InexactNumberQ@Unevaluated@x]], Hold@expr], n];
```

we can run the following

```
RationalizedN[g[0.2, 3737, 0.1435, 0.9481, -0.0920, 42.0*10^13], 50]
```

which yields

> `1.0000000000000000000000000000000000001176153321857`