# Error "is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision \ may be lost " for small values in Plot

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I'm trying to plot two curves but I'm having issues with the lower end of the range:

```
Clear[t, a0, \[Alpha], \[Delta], \[CapitalTheta], lmin, lmin2, ebar, \
nmin, nmin2]
a0 = 2.4*10^-10;
\[Alpha] = 10;
\[Delta] = 1/100;
\[CapitalTheta] = 0.1;
lmin = a0*nmin;
lmin2 = a0*nmin2;
ebar = ((t/\[CapitalTheta])^2)*
   Integrate[x/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, \[CapitalTheta]/t}];
nmin = (4*\[CapitalTheta]*\[Alpha])/(t*
      ebar)*((ebar/\[Alpha]) + (1/4))^2;
nmin2 = (2 \[Alpha]/\[Delta])*(\[CapitalTheta]/t)*ebar;
LogLogPlot[{nmin, nmin2}, {t, 10^-4, 10^3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I keep getting one error and the plot won't show the values for t<10^-2. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Integrate use [NIntegrate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html), since you want numerical solutions. Also, there is a variable of t in integration, for that, you can use [:= (Set Delayed)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html).

```
Clear[t, a0, \[Alpha], \[Delta], \[CapitalTheta], lmin, lmin2, ebar, nmin, nmin2]
a0 = 2.4*10^-10;
\[Alpha] = 10;
\[Delta] = 1/100;
\[CapitalTheta] = 0.1;
lmin = a0*nmin;
lmin2 = a0*nmin2;
ebar[t_] := ((t/\[CapitalTheta])^2)*
NIntegrate[x/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, \[CapitalTheta]/t}];
nmin[t_] := (4*\[CapitalTheta]*\[Alpha])/(t*ebar[t])*((ebar[t]/\[Alpha]) + (1/4))^2;
nmin2[t_] := (2 \[Alpha]/\[Delta])*(\[CapitalTheta]/t)*ebar[t];
LogLogPlot[{nmin[t], nmin2[t]}, {t, 10^-4, 10^3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The underflow is not a significant error.  There is a numerics issue with $\log(1+x)$ when $|x| <\mkern-4mu< 1$.  Since $\log(1+x)$ is asymptotic to $x$ as $x\rightarrow0$, underflow in $x$ corresponds to underflow in $\log(1+x)$ so there's little to be done. If it's a problem, then use a higher `WorkingPrecision`, which just pushes back the underflow problem (hopefully to a point at which it is negligible).

The real problem that shows up in the plot is loss of precision in the machine-precision argument `1 + x`.  Since floating-point has a fixed-width mantissa, when `x` is smaller than `1`, significant bits are lost; when `x` is much smaller than `1`, many signficant bits are lost. Since the result of `Log[1 + x]` is approximately `x`, that loss of significance can be, well, significant.  There is function `log1p` in many math libraries that handles this.  It's available in Mathematica as `` Internal`Log1p[] ``, but it is not in the `` System` ``  context; see
[Elegant high precision `log1p`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39126/elegant-high-precision-log1p)

We can turn off the warning message for a session with `Off[]` (until turned back on with `On[]`) or temporarily for a computation with `Quiet[]`.

```
Clear[t, a0, α, δ, Θ, lmin, lmin2, ebar, nmin, nmin2]
a0 = 2.4*10^-10;
α = 10;
δ = 1/100;
ebar = ((t/Θ)^2)*
    Integrate[x/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, Θ/t}, 
     Assumptions -> Θ > 0 && t > 0] /. 
   Log[x_] :> Internal`Log1p[x - 1 // Simplify];
Θ = 0.1;
nmin = (4*Θ*α)/(t*ebar)*((ebar/α) + (1/4))^2;
nmin2 = (2 α/δ)*(Θ/t)*ebar;
Quiet[
 LogLogPlot[{nmin, nmin2}, {t, 10^-4, 10^3}, PlotRange -> All],
 General::munfl]
```

[image]